# JS Function With Two Parentheses and Two Params

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how a function works that is run with two parentheses and two parameters. Like so:

```
add(10)(10); // returns 20
```

I know how to write one that takes two params like so:

```
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

add(10,10); // returns 20
```

How could I alter that function so it could be run with one set of parameters, or two, and produce the same result?

Any help is appreciated. Literally scratching my head over this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"How could I alter that function so it could be run with one set of parameters, or two, and produce the same result?"* Why would you *want* to?

Comment: ^^ This.  Please explain what you are trying to do, not how you think you should do it.

Comment: Thanks @Abdul for finding the dupe

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In some languages _it's the exact same thing_, for example - Haskell and F#.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Interesting. Yeah, I haven't got into the pure functional languages.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well, in a line - you can use partial application to get _context_, imagine you have a function that connects to a database and takes a connection string and a table, so calling `connect("connString", "tableName")` is useful, but you usually really want to do `let table = connect("connString");` and then do `table("tableName)` all around without having to type the connection string over and over :)

Comment: near duplicate (subset, actually) of the poorly named http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376702/tail-function-in-javascript

Comment: @Touffy: I think that's a very different question.  Certainly it has a very different answer.

Comment: @ScottSauyet It's a generalization of this question to *n* arguments, and the answer it gives is totally applicable here. Yes, they're different, which is why I didn't flag as duplicate. But finding a special solution for *n* = 2 when there's a nice one for any *n* still seems like a waste of time.

Comment: @Touffy: A generalization to _n_ arguments for a fixed _n_ would make sense, and my answer below answers that question as well.  But the linked question is to my mind substantially different: it wants to call an unlimited number of arguments, and then either automatically (via `valueOf` in some answers) or by a call with no parameters (in others) manually end the chain of calls.  It's not just the implementation which is different, but the fundamental API.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> How could I alter that function so it could be run with one set of parameters, or two, and produce the same result?

You can *almost* do that, but I'm struggling to think of a good reason to.

Here's how: You detect how many arguments your function has received and, if it's received only one, you return a function instead of a number — and have *that* function add in the second number if it gets called:

```js
function add(a,b) {
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    return function(b2) { // You could call this arg `b` as well if you like,
      return a + b2;      // it would shadow (hide, supercede) the one above
    };
  }
  return a + b;
}
console.log(add(10, 10)); // 20
console.log(add(10)(10)); // 20
```

I said "*almost*" above because just because the `add` function received only one argument, that doesn't guarantee that the caller is going to call the result. They could write:

```
var x = add(10);
```

...and never call the function that `x` now refers to.

Comment: It could be really fun to generalize it to "autocurry" (that is, calling `autocurry`) on a function does this for N arguments and then showing really useful examples of [point-free programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) - pretty much similar to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3svKOdZijA)

Comment: If you're looking for good reasons to do this, check out the Lonsdorf video Benjamin mentions, or the post from Jackson linked in my answer.  It can lead to some really readable code.

Comment: I never knew you could detect the arguments being passed. Really helpful! Thanks for this.

Comment: if i need 'catch' to manage errors  in 'add(10)(10)', where to do it ? at the end i have error

Comment: @stackdave: Not sure what you're asking. Just a `try`/`catch` around the call should do it.

Answer (score 13):

#### Welcome to the wonderful world of first order functions

In JavaScript, a function can *return* a function since a function is just another object. A simple implementation is something like:

```
function add(x){
    return function addOther(y){
        return x + y;
    };
}
```

This is possible because of [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and first order functions.

This also lets you do partial application, libraries like [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/) utilize this to great extent.

```
var addThree = add(3)
addThree(5); // 8
```

Comment: *"...so it could be run with one set of parameters, **or two**, and produce the same result..."* (my emphasis)

Comment: I know what OP asked for (thanks for making sure though, honest), I read his question and then _chose to answer a slightly different one_ to keep it simple.

Comment: ... and the Ramda answer does allow it to be run either way.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

To extend what both [T. J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29822083/1243641) and [Benjamin Gruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29822083/1243641) said, libraries like [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/) (disclosure: I'm one of the authors) allow you to convert a simple function like this:

```
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

into the style under discussion by wrapping it in a call to a `curry` function:

```
var add = R.curry(function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
});

add(3, 5); //=> 8
add(3)(5); //=> 8
var add3 = add(3);
add3(5); //=> 8
```

The best article I know on this subject is Hugh Jackson's [Why Curry Helps](http://hughfdjackson.com/javascript/why-curry-helps/).  I wrote a more detailed one at [Favoring Curry](http://fr.umio.us/favoring-curry/).

---

### Update

Here is a version of `curry` somewhat simpler than the one in Ramda.  It would do the above and quite a bit more, but doesn't do some of the things that Ramda does with placeholder values:

```
// here is a function that takes a function and returns a curried version
// of it, that is, a version that performs the sort of partial application
// you describe.
var curry = function(fn) {
    // first, we detect how many arguments the function has.
    var fnArity = fn.length; 
    var partialApply = function(args) { 
        // now, let's create a function that's curried
        return function () {
            // collect the previous args as the partial, and add the new 
            // ones you just received
            var newArgs = (args || []).concat([].slice.call(arguments, 0));
            // if we have "enough" arguments, we don't need any more partial
            // application and we can call the function.
            if (newArgs.length >= fnArity) {
                return fn.apply(this, newArgs);
            } else { // else we return a partially applied version
                return partialApply(newArgs);
            }
        };
    };

    return partialApply([]); // a function is itself partially applied with 0 args
};
```

Comment: I was looking for a pure JS way, but I've given Curry a look and it looks very interesting nonetheless. I might use it on a future project. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottSauyet thanks, that's much better :) I've added comments to the implementation, feel free to revert and/or change some of the changes I made - some of the comments are over pretty trivial code bits but I think all of it would benefit someone who has not done any currying before.

Comment: Thank you @BenjaminGruenbaum for all the annotations!

Answer (score 0):

```
function add() {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    sum += arguments[i];
  }
  function total() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      sum += arguments[i];
    }
    return total;
  }
  total.toString = function () { return sum };

  return total;
}
```

This will work for any no of arguments and parentheses.

https://medium.com/@imdebasispanda/super-function-with-closure-86a58a9a980b